# control transformer

Tags: transformer, control

In control transformer ,used in Switchgear i.e. 415V/240V—this transformer is single phase transformer or 2-phase transformer?

As primary is 415 V which is tapped from 2 phase….while secondary is 240 V single phase supply…

Do you have anything that describe this trafo?

Answer (score 1):

That is a single phase transformer. The phases of the transformer refer to the distinct phase relationships between windings. In the this case there is a single primary and secondary winding, and therefore is a single phase transformer.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be a single phase transformer but it's connected to two phases of a three phase supply. Is this the confusing issue? Normal 240V primary transformers are connected to a single phase and the neutral point. If you do the math you find that the voltage between two phases of a three phase supply is sqrt(3) * 240v which is of course 415V.